# Comparison test for convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^{\delta}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the comparison test for convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^{\delta}}$$

The series converges for $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $~k=\dfrac1\delta~=>~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt[^k]x}~dx=k!\qquad$ See [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more details.